# Odoo python module: Create multiple records based on month

Tags: python, postgresql, tree, odoo, odoo-13

I am new to Odoo and psql in general and hit a wall recently. I want to create a module where i select a type (e.g. outgoing invoices) and a date and create records based on what is found in the database. I have problems with a datetime field (not sure how to use store/required). This is what i got so far:

Module in models.py:

```
class bmd_test(models.Model):
    """BMD Eingangsrechnungen Buchungen Model, New Approach"""
    _name = 'bmd.test'
    # _auto = False
    
    date_order = fields.Datetime(string="Date", invisible=True,
                                help="Select ending date.")
    beleg_typen = fields.Selection([('ER', 'Eingangsrechnungen Buchungen'), ('ERP', 'Eingangsrechnungen Personenkonten'), 
                                    ('AR', 'Ausgangsrechnungen Buchungen'), ('ARP', 'Ausgangsrechnungne Personenkonten'), 
                                    ('BK', 'Bankbuchungen mit Auszifferung'), 
                                    ('LG', 'Lohnbuchungen'),
                                    ('EB', 'Eröffnungsbilanzbuchungen'),
                                    ('UB', 'Umbuchungen'), 
                                    ('EA', 'Spesenabrechnung')], string='Belegtyp')
    chosen_beleg = fields.Char(string='buchsymbol', compute="_get_beleg", store=True)

    cost_center = fields.Char(string='cost center')
    
    @api.depends('beleg_typen')
    def _get_beleg(self):
        for record in self:
            record.chosen_beleg = str(record.beleg_typen)
        # TODO: this is the problem part (creates more than 3 entries). Do i need @api.model?
        # for i in range(3):  
        #     self.env['bmd.auto'].create({'cost_center': str(i)})
```

Also i would like to add a button to my tree-view in views.xml, but im not sure about my XML code either:

```
    <record id="bmd.list_test" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="name">BMD list test</field>
      <field name="model">bmd.test</field>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <!-- I tried adding a form here, put the tree inside a form, headers/footers with buttons,  but none worked.-->
        <tree>
          <field name="chosen_beleg"/>
          <field name="cost_center"/>
        </tree>
      </field>
    </record>

    <record id="bmd.action_window_test" model="ir.actions.act_window">
      <field name="name">TriLite BMD module: Test View</field>
      <field name="res_model">bmd.test</field>
        <!-- Here i tried view_mode form, but then i lose the view of the records..-->
      <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    </record>

    <menuitem name="BMD TEST" id="bmd.menu_test" parent="bmd.menu_root" action="bmd.action_window_test"/>
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your requirement here, because i don't see the relation between `bmd.auto` and `bmd.test`. And don't create records in compute methods. Make another method which can be used in the tree view with `<button type="object" name="method_name"` and so on. And please tell us which Odoo version you use, because some things differ between them (for example the api decorators changed a bit).

Comment: Hey CZoellner, thanks for your reply. Youre right, in this example there is no relation between bmd.auto and bmd.test, the commented code was inserted from another model. I am using Odoo 13. I created a separate function and called it with a button, which works great, thanks for that input. Can i also add the button in the create form instead of the list view?

Comment: yes you can do that.